# Type casted pointer constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor, casting

I am type casting a class to use storage set by another class. I want to invoke the constructor of the first class when type casting is performed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Consider the following code:

```
class A{
      int x;
public:
      A() {x = 0;}
};

class B{
      double x;
public:
      B() {x =0.0f;}
};

B * bObj = new();
A * aObj = reinterpret_cast < A * > ( bObj );     //Just for the sake of explaining
```

Now **aObj** references to the memory allocated to **bObj** & uses it & stores its contents there.
I am trying to get the **constructor of A class** called when the typecasting is performed or after. Please help.

I want to use **aObj** and the constructor for A to be called. which doesn't happen. **aObj** is, no doubt ,getting memory allocated however, the constructor call doesn't happen. And it has garbage values filled in it.

Comment: Could you describe the *actual problem* you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: "And it has garbage values filled in it." If course it does, because you're invoking UB by the way you're using `reinterpret_cast`. Please explain why you think you need to do this...

Comment: @NPE: I am learning C++ and trying to store objects in a universal buffer. (bObj acting as buffer in above snippet). aObj does have memory access but constructor call doesn't happen which Is what i m trying to achieve.

Comment: A cast operator doesn't call the constructor of the target type. Your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : Agreed. I am trying to get the constructor call done somehow. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am learning C++ and trying to store objects in a universal buffer. (bObj acting as buffer in above snippet). aObj does have memory access but constructor call doesn't happen which Is what i m trying to achieve.

It sounds like you need to read up on placement `new`. See [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) and [What is "placement new" and why would I use it?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) for some background and examples of use.

Bear in mind that using placement `new` correctly requires care. It is very easy to get it wrong and end up with [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In particular, you'll need to rethink how you allocate the buffer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I find your comment misleading. Placement `new` is probably the best tool for the stated problem ("store objects in a universal buffer"). I don't think it is our place to judge how qualified the OP is and decide for them which tools they should be allowed to use.

Comment: your response comment is actively misleading. The stated problem is **not** to "store objects in a universal buffer".

Comment: @NPE tx for the help ! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing an `A` object in the storage of a `B` object is generally Undefined Behavior.

You can do it (with a placement new expression) when type `B` is an array of `char`, not a class with a constructor, but it's extremely rarely needed, only for experts, and it requires manual invocation of the `A` object's destructor.

If you are trying to just save memory then you can

- Ignore the memory usage.
  With today's computers that's generally the best solution.
- Use derived classes and virtual member functions.
- In the worst case, use a tagged `union`.
  "Tagged" means that there is a type identification value, a type "tag".

If you are trying to save execution time for PIMPL idiom,

- Measure. Probably avoiding a dynamic allocation and indirection isn't really so critical.

If something else, please state what.

Comment: placement new works well for me as suggested originally by NPE. Thank you for your input as well.

Comment: @user3368334: it may appear to "work" but it's **undefined behavior**. that means that you'll get a visit from Mr. Murphy at the most inconvenient time.